# Kentico news pagination not

Tags: repeater, kentico

I created a news page in aspx using a repeater with the bellow properties:

```
  <cms:CMSRepeater ID="CMSRepeater2" runat="server" ClassNames="cms.news" TransformationName="cms.news.preview" 
  SelectedItemTransformationName="cms.news.default" ItemSeparator="<hr/>" Pagesize="20">
             </cms:CMSRepeater>
```

I tried creating a pagination for this but not achieved. How do I manage pagination with news repeater?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
<cms:CMSRepeaterWithEffect ID="CMSRepeater2" runat="server" ClassNames="cms.news" TransformationName="cms.news.preview" EnablePaging="true"
  SelectedItemTransformationName="cms.news.default" ItemSeparator="<hr/>" Pagesize="20">
             </cms:CMSRepeater>
```

There are a few differences between the two web parts, but I find paging to just work a lot better on the Repeater With effect. I'm not 100% convinced that the standard CMSRepeater web part even does anything with those properties without being hooked up to a separate paging control in some way, I could be wrong about that last part though.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to set the "EnablePaging" propety to true as well as the "PagingMode" property (querystring or postback)?

Comment: the property PagingMode is not recognized.

Comment: It seems you are using CMSRepeater control. In this case you can set the mode in the code behind: <repeaterControl>.PagerControl.PagingMode = <value>;